# echo value from radio box

Tags: php

I'm trying to have an email send on submit, but I can't figure out how to echo the value of a radio box, and the text in the value. Can anyone help me?

Here's my radio box:

```
 <label>
          <input type="radio" name="question8" value="0;Not at all" id="question8_1" />
          Not at all</label>
        <br />
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="question8" value="25;Slightly" id="question8_2" />
          Slightly</label>
        <br />
        <label>
```

Comment: <?php echo $_POST['question8'];
?> If that doesn't work, show your server-side code and the HTML of the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your form was submitted via post,

```
echo $_POST['question8'];
```

If for some reason it was submitted via `$_GET`

```
echo $_GET['question8'];
```

To separate the value and text, use `explode(";", $value)`:

```
$radio = explode(";", $_POST['question8']);
$radioval = $radio[0];
$radiotext = $radio[1];

echo "Total $radioval: Answer: $radiotext";

// Or the same thing tidier, via list() multi-assignment
list($radioval, $radiotext) = explode(";", $_POST['question8']);
```

And both of these assume your `<input>` tags actually occur inside a `<form>` tag as in:

```
 <form action='somepage.php' method='post'>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="question8" value="0;Not at all" id="question8_1" />
      Not at all</label>
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="question8" value="25;Slightly" id="question8_2" />
      Slightly</label>
    <br />
    <label>
 </form>
```

Comment: Just checked that. Is there a way to echo the number, then the text? So it would say "Total=25" "Answer: Slightly"?

Comment: wouldn't you want to use `$_POST['question8_1']` and `$_POST['question8_2']`?

Comment: @Shredder No, the `name` attribute is what is known to `$_POST`, not the `id` attrs. Those would be useful in javascipt, but not to PHP.

Comment: Also if you change the names of the radio boxes you turn them into functioning like a check box.. But I do have checkboxes set up that way.

Comment: To push this question further, it is possible to get the sum of all the exploded numerical values?

Comment: @kamalo If you have multiple radio buttons like `$_POST['question1']` through `$_POST['question8']` whenever you explode one, just add `$total += $radioval;`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the data from the $_GET, $_POST, or $_REQUEST variables ($_REQUEST will do either post or get requests) just use the name that your radio box has:

```
$value = $_REQUEST['question8'];
echo $value;
```

Also, of course make sure that the form that the radio boxes are part of is pointed at the correct php script for this to work. (they are part of a form right?)